# Is there a way to obtain the pageID of any Facebook url, using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

Given a Facebook page url, I want to be able to create fb:// links, which requires the pageID of said url. Has anyone done this and/or knows if it's even possible? I'm using node.

Thankful for any help.

Comment: Via API it would easily be possible, a request for `/pagename` will return the ID - but you would have to get your app approved for the use of either the Page Public Content Access or Page Public Metadata Access feature first (the second one probably makes more sense), because otherwise you have no API access to pages that your user doesn't have an admin role on any more.

Comment: Which API are you referring to?

Comment: Facebook's Graph API

Comment: Can you point more specifically to an endpoint in the API doing what you describe?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ That you can also use the page username instead of the page ID, is not explicitly mentioned there any more as far as I can see, but it works. And the feature you would need to get approved, is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-metadata-access Whether they _will_ approve that for your purpose though, is not guaranteed. (Valid use cases are listed on the page, not sure if yours would also qualify.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I see nothing on that first link related with what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: That _is_ the documentation of the pages endpoint, as you asked for. As I said, you only need to make a request for `/pagename`, and you will get a JSON with that name and the id back. If you have no idea how the API works as of yet, then you will have to go and start with the basics, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/get-started